# How should I implement Comparable when equals() and hashCode() are not defined?

Tags: java, comparable

The code my team is working on has several classes where `equals` and `hashCode` are not defined in the class hierarchy. We'd like to implement `Comparable` such that `compareTo` is consistent with `equals` using `hashCode`, like so:

```
class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass>
{
    private String myProperty;
    // Other properties, etc.
    ....

    public int compareTo(MyClass obj) {
        // Natural ordering comparisons
        ...
        // Reach here if natural ordering properties are equivalent
        return new Integer(this.hashCode()).compareTo(new Integer(obj.hashCode());
    }
}
```

Is this considered a valid means of implementing `Comparable`? Are there any pitfalls with using the default `hashCode` implementation that I should be aware of?

**UPDATE:** The behavior we're striving for is as follows:

1. The class properties are compared first, in a natural ordering we define.
2. If a given property for the two objects are equivalent, we move on to the next one in the ordering.
3. If all properties are equivalent, we return 0 only if `this.equals(obj)`.

Comment: The internal `hashCode()` might not give you the same results for objects with the same values, better to define your own.

Comment: It's all about on which criteria you want to compare your objects.

Comment: I usually prefer in-line anonymous definitions of Comparable, but I think this is perfectly acceptable to put the implementation into your domain objects when you need to always use the same sort everywhere.  However, like @HunterMcMillen says, hashCode is not really something you would use to compare.  Hashes can be re-used.  You are better off comparing the parts you want on your own.

Answer (score 0):

No, This is not the valid means of implementing Comparable. Because , suppose your all natural ordering comparison for two different objects of `MyClass` within `equals` method comes true , after that when hashcode of two objects are compared it would return `false` . This is so because in this case `hashcode` method of `Object` class would be called by default(as you have not provided your own hashcode method), Which will be different for different objects. Hence the two objects of MyClass will never be equal no matter if all natural ordering comparison comes out to be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a valid way. Apparently you want a fixed ordering for objects which are equal on other values (am I right? You did not explain your aim with the hashcode usage here). 
The only thing i would do is copy the java code of Integer.compareTo() in your compareTo method, so you do not have to create 2 Integers for every comparison.

Comment: Thanks - I hope I clarified my usage of `hashCode()` with my update.

Comment: on "3. we return 0 only if this.equals(obj)." -> then use equals, not hashcode, otherwise you could have a rare hashcode clash (two objects returning the same hash). Another thing: what should it do if they are not equal? return negative or positive and why?

Comment: Thanks @bluevoid for reminding me of the possiblity of collisions. Returning 0 only if `equals` is true makes sense. If not, then in order to satisfy the `Comparable` contract we have to return -1 if `!a.equals(b)` and 1 if `!b.equals(a)`. Returning a default -1 or 1 would make the `compareTo` violate the transitivity requirement.